# Produce summary of thread utilisation

Tags: java, perl, powershell

I have an application that writes out logs every time a request is made to it. The date and time info refer to the end time of the function. By using the execution time we calculate the time the request started.

Here is what the logs currently look like:

```
year | month | day | hour | minute | seconds | Thread | UserName           | ExecTime
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 300     | 1      | file_download      | 33.86
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 45      | 1      | file_upload        | 0.359
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 55      | 1      | folder_browse      | 0.234
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 11      | 1      | sending_email      | 0.14
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 20      | 1      | browsing_favorites | 0.985
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 29      | 1      | file_download      | 0.266
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 33      | 1      | file_upload        | 0.296
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 37      | 1      | file_zip           | 0.25
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 41      | 1      | view_properties    | 0.0
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 46      | 1      | file_download      | 0.187
```

***Illustration purposes only***

As a request could span several minutes or even hours it becomes hard to calculate each thread's utilisation on a minute by minute basis. The following output illustrates the output I am after:

```
Thread | month | day | hour | minute | % Busy
1      | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 0.5
2      | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 0.1
3      | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 0.9
```

***Illustration purposes only***

For example, if a request started executing at 12:30:30 and ended at 12:32:30 the above table would look like:

```
Thread | month | day | hour | minute | % Busy
1      | 3     | 26  | 12   | 29     | 0
1      | 3     | 26  | 12   | 30     | 0.5
1      | 3     | 26  | 12   | 31     | 1
1      | 3     | 26  | 12   | 32     | 0.5
1      | 3     | 26  | 12   | 33     | 0
```

***Illustration purposes only***

The number of minutes in the output will be the number of minutes between the first request and last request that can be found in the logs.

**UPDATE**

Here is a summary taken from @TessellatingHeckler request for clarification:

1. calculate start time
2. for the start/end partial minutes calculate the utilisation fraction.
3. Count minutes inbetween as 100% busy
4. Add multiple requests/start-end overlaps within each minute.
5. Fill in missing minutes as 0% busy.
6. Present a list per thread, from the calculated start of the first entry to the last entry, showing datetime to the minute and %busy

I know this is hard but I just need an approach that will translate well to code. I am happy to use perl, powershell or java.

Thanks

Comment: I don't get what you want. Your example output shows Thread 1, at 8:57, 0.5% busy. Yet the input shows it had ExecTime 33 seconds at 8:57:32. Why isn't it ~50% busy for that minute? Or ~25% busy for the two minutes in the input range? From 8:57:32, 33 seconds ExecTime carries it over a minute boundary (from previous minute or into following minute), how do you want to account for that? Yet if all you want is the % busy per minute, all you are doing is throwing the seconds away and calculating time/60, which isn't much of a stats calculation.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Sorry, that code was for illustration purposes only and not mathematically correct. I should have pointed that out. I will correct that in my question.

Comment: is my understanding right? A request finishes, writes a log entry (end time, thread no., duration). You want: 1) calculate start time, 2) for the start/end partial minutes, calculate the busyness fraction. 3) Count minutes inbetween as 100% busy, 4) Add multiple requests/start-end overlaps within each minute. 5) Fill in missing minutes as 0% busy. 5) Present a list per thread, from the calculated start of the first entry to the last entry, showing datetime to the minute and %busy.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That is exactly it!

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following will do most of the work for you.  You'll have to figure out what Busy actually means on your own though:

```
use List::Util qw(sum);

use strict;
use warnings;

<DATA>; # Skip Header

my %thread;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @data = split /\s*\|\s*/;
    push @{$thread{$data[6]}}, \@data;
}

print "Thread | month | day | hour | minute | ExecTime\n";
for my $id (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %thread) {
    my $time = sum map {$_->[7]} @{$thread{$id}};
    printf "%-6s | %-5s | %-3s | %-4s | %-6s | %.03f\n", $id, @{$thread{$id}[0]}[1,2,3,4], $time;
}

__DATA__
year | month | day | hour | minute | seconds | Thread |  ExecTime ( seconds )
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 32      | 1      |  33.86
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 45      | 2      |  0.359
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 55      | 3      |  0.234
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 11      | 1      |  0.14
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 20      | 2      |  0.985
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 29      | 3      |  0.266
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 33      | 3      |  0.296
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 37      | 1      |  0.25
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 41      | 2      |  0.0
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 46      | 1      |  0.187
```

Outputs:

```
Thread | month | day | hour | minute | ExecTime
1      | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 34.437
2      | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 1.344
3      | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 0.796
```

Comment: Why is your output saying Thread 1 had 34 seconds of ExecTime in minute 57, when ... it didn't?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler When combining the thread values, I chose to go with the minimum time, like he did in his example.  That is all.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand all the parts in your request, but I gave it a shot in PowerShell. The script does the following:

- Estimates the starttime for each line(date specified in columns - exectime(seconds))
- Returns one line per thread per minute(based on starttime)
- `% Busy` returns ExecTime/60seconds, so 60sec ExecTime would be 100% utilization
- Returns 0% busy for each minute that isn't accounted for in the log.

Known issues:

- ExecTime is not split into minutes. `% Busy` returns seconds/60sec for the starttime-minute. So ex. an operation that stopped 8.57.32 and lastet 34 seconds, will actually show up as 56% busy for the 56th minute. To solve this, we would have to process each ExecTime in a thread-group and sum up all the ExecTime-parts per minute in a hashtable until all ExecTimes were processed, and then create the results based on the exectime-sum for each minute in the hashtable.

Script:

```
$path = c:\test.txt
$data = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($path).Replace(" ","") | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "|"

$data | Group-Object Thread | % {

    #Get start-time
    $_.Group | % { $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name StartTime -Value ([datetime]("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5}" -f $_.month, $_.day, $_.year, $_.hour, $_.minute, $_.seconds)).AddSeconds(-($_.ExecTime)) }

    #Group by minute
    $_.Group | Group-Object {$_.starttime.minute} | % {
        #Report per minute
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            "Thread" = $_.Group[0].thread
            "Month" = $_.Group[0].starttime.month
            "Day" = $_.Group[0].starttime.day
            "Hour" = $_.Group[0].starttime.hour
            "Minute" = $_.Group[0].starttime.minute
            "% Busy" = [math]::Round((($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property ExecTime -Sum).Sum / 60 * 100),2)
        }
    }

    #Create 0% record for missing minutes
    $min = ($_.Group | Sort-Object StartTime)[0].StartTime
    $max = ($_.Group | Sort-Object StartTime)[-1].StartTime

    for($d = $min; $d -le $max; $d = $d.AddMinutes(1)) {
        if(-not ($_.Group | ? { $_.StartTime.Minute -eq $d.Minute })) {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{
                "Thread" = $_.Group[0].thread
                "Month" = $d.Month
                "Day" = $d.Day
                "Hour" = $d.Hour
                "Minute" = $d.Minute
                "% Busy" = 0
            }
        }
    }


} | Sort-Object Day, Hour, Minute, Thread | Select-Object "Thread", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "% Busy"
```

test.txt

```
year | month | day | hour | minute | seconds | Thread |  ExecTime
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 32      | 1      |  33.86
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 45      | 2      |  0.359
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 57     | 55      | 3      |  0.234
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 11      | 1      |  0.14
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 20      | 2      |  0.985
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 29      | 3      |  0.266
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 33      | 3      |  0.296
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 37      | 1      |  0.25
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 41      | 2      |  0.0
2014 | 3     | 26  | 8    | 58     | 46      | 1      |  0.187
2014 | 3     | 26  | 9    | 00     | 5       | 1      |  0.0
2014 | 3     | 26  | 9    | 00     | 8       | 1      |  0.187
```

Output:

```
Thread Month Day Hour Minute % Busy
------ ----- --- ---- ------ ------
1          3  26    8     56  56,43
1          3  26    8     57      0
2          3  26    8     57    0,6
3          3  26    8     57   0,39
1          3  26    8     58   0,96
2          3  26    8     58   1,64
3          3  26    8     58   0,94
1          3  26    8     59      0
1          3  26    9      0   0,31
```

I will probably not fix any errors in this, so feel free to edit the answer to fix bugs or extend it. This was just an attempt to get ball rolling. :)

Comment: Just messed about with this powershell and unfortunately it doesn't perform well enough i.e. 600,000 rows of requests take too long.